# How to get t statistic with simulation?

Tags: simulation

I got a single t statistic value with the following codes. The codes worked.
set.seed(2)

```
n<- 10
b0 <- 1.5
b1 <- 2
U<-rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=2)
X<-rnorm(n, mean=5, sd=5)
Y<-b0+b1*X+U
DY<-diff(Y)
FY<-lag(Y,-1)
model1<-lm(DY[2:10]~FY[2:10])
katsayi<-summary(model1)[[4]][[2,1]]
std<-summary(model1)[[4]][[2,2]]
ist<-katsayi/std
```

For 20 of them (ie for simulation), I ran the code below. However, I have shortcomings, I got 20 same coefficients. I'm very new to R program, I would be very glad if you could help.

```
set.seed(2) 
n<- 10
M<- 20
katsayi<-numeric(M)
std<-numeric(M)
b0 <- 1.5
b1 <- 2
U<-rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=2)
X<-rnorm(n, mean=5, sd=5)
Y<-b0+b1*X+U
DY<-diff(Y)
FY<-lag(Y,-1)
for (i in 1:M){
model1<-lm(DY[2:10]~FY[2:10])
katsayi[i]<-summary(model1)[[4]][[2,1]]
std[i]<-summary(model1)[[4]][[2,2]]
ist<-katsayi/std
}
```

Comment: You run a model on the same data 20 times, so of course you get the same estimates each time. Tip: indent your code, then this kind of error is much easier to spot. (Also, work with spaces, especially around your assignment operators. If you ever want to compare whether `i` is smaller than $-1$, then `i<-1` will give you a very hard to find bug.)

Comment: Thank you so much @StephanKolassa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re generating DY and FY once, before the for loop. So, the for loop is generating coefficients for the exact same data. Try moving all code related to generating data inside the for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much @clementzach